# Which Operations are Considered in the FLOPS Measure?

Tags: performance, cpu, gpu

FLOPS (floating point operations per second) is a standard measure of performance of computing.

But, which floating point operations are considered? Addition? Multplication? Division? Doesn't each one of these take a different numbet of cycles to perform?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/329174/2947502

Answer (score 0):

FLOPS is a measure usually associated with graphics cards (as it is a somewhat less useful measure in other areas).

Typically what is measured there is the performance of the fused multiply-add instruction [FMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiply%E2%80%93accumulate_operation#Fused_multiply.E2.80.93add). This means that a GPU that is stated to have a peak performance of 1 TFLOPS will do a maximum of 1 trillion floating point operations of the form a * b + c = d in a second.

The reason this operation is used is that it is very essential to most operations a typical computer graphics application has to perform, such as computing the dot-product of vectors or multiplying matrices.